# k-Means clustering order

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I followed the k-Means tutorial for Python:

https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.11-k-means.html

But my question is more generally about the k-Means function of Python included in sklearn as well as in openCV:

If I repeat the same k-Means clustering function to the same image again and again, the numbering of the found classes differs. This makes a naming of the clusters difficult.
Can you help me understand this?
Is the analysis of an image not occuring in the same way whenever I run a k-Means function over it (same numer of classes assumed)?

Following a visualization of my question:
Two plots with the same script over the same image. The clustering of pixel groups seem to show the same result but in a different order (visualized by different colors):

[image]

Thanks,
Swawa

Comment: This is because the model groups the data independent of the original labels. See [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224759/how-to-avoid-k-means-assigning-different-labels-on-different-run) for more discussion.

Comment: This is due to random initialization of kmeans centroids. I'm not 100% sure but you can try to specify `random_state`, you will get same clustering result for sure, but I'm not sure if the ordering will be the same or not.